# Is it possible to use an angular component in a slot of a webcomponent

Tags: angular, web-component, lit-element, lit

In my angular app (Angular v12 or latest), I'm using a custom library of webcomponents.

One of this is a modal, with a slot (something like this : https://www.npmjs.com/package/@obsidiansoft/native-modal )

*(Sorry, I'm not authorized to link the code.)*

I'm trying to display an angular component in my modal, but when inspecting the modal DOM, I have something like :

```
<modal>
  <app-my-custom-component></app-my-custom-component>
</modal>
```

Angular is not rendering the html behing "app-my-custom-component" in the modal.

The modal is working properly when the content is pure HTML :

```
<modal>
  <p>A basic content</p>
</modal>
```

render correctly in the browser.

Is this usage possible ? What Angular configuration do I need ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lit-elements returns Shadow DOM elements, which will not be directly accessible.
So even if you try to insert an Angular Component in Lit-Element Component, than your Angular App will not be able to react to the Shadow DOM and the custom-element(angular element/component) you have added.

And yes from the performance and architectural perspective, this doesn't seems to be a good idea.

Comment: We use Angular components and lit-element in our application, so it is possible. I don't know why it is not working in this case. Lit-element generates a shadow dom, but the angular component you add to the slot is rendered in the Angular template or light dom, so I suspect there is more going on there than incompatibility.

Comment: I agree with @Mike Broughton, web components slots are accessible from the lightdom, so this should work.